# I have a problem with a very simple table

Tags: tables

I have a problem creating a table. Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | c c c c | c c c c |}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Errore \% con valori massimi} &  \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Errore \% con valori minimi} \\ \hline \hline
Parametro & H & X & T & L & H & X & T & L \\ \hline
$\epsilon$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:errore_percentuale}
\caption{Errore percentuale medio .}% title of Table
\end{table}
```

And this is what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see the letters `H`, `X` and `T` are grouped together while `L` is not! So here is my question: how can I have the letters `H`, `X`, `T` and `L` equally separated in both boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Errore \% con valori massimi}` and `\multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Errore \% con valori minimi}` occupy more space than H, X, T and L put together and the excess width is compensated with the last column i.e., with L. You can define a new column with enough width:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}}
```

and then

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | *{4}{C} | *{4}{C} |}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Errore \% con valori massimi} &  \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Errore \% con valori minimi} \\ \hline \hline
Parametro & H & X & T & L & H & X & T & L \\ \hline
$\epsilon$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:errore_percentuale}
\caption{Errore percentuale medio .}% title of Table
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I haven't modified the extra lines in the first cell as I didn't know your intentions exactly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! thank you so much||